Positive Harmonic function on punctured space is constant
I have read this question on Harmonic Function Theory by Sheldon Axler; Paul Bourdon; Wade Ramey

I know when $\lim_{x\to0}|x|^{n-2}u(x)=0$,then u can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $u$ is positive, by Liouville theorem, we conclude $u\equiv a$ for some constant $a$.
However, I don't know how to solve the problem in other cases.
Can anyone provide some ideas? Thanks!

I have found the answer to it!Just in the same book there's a theorem called Bocher's theorem considering the same problem.
